# featured_image throwing 401 error: json_user_cannot_read

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress json api plugin and create custom post type advertisement when i upload a existing image it return an error : featured_image throwing 401 error: json_user_cannot_read

Comment: Please, have a look to :[Post featured image json_user_cannot_read error](http://wordpress.ahlekhabar.com/support/topic/post-featured-image-json_user_cannot_read-error)

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec :) but it still not working i cannot understand the error can you please tell me my error, I think my basic auth plugin is not working properly i cannot acces my meta (data ) of the posts here is the link of api :http://abc/wp-json/posts/1/meta  and    it shows the given error     : 
               
[
  {
    "code": "json_cannot_edit",
    "message": "Sorry, you cannot edit this post"
  }
]

thanks in advance:)